# operator Overloading and mutex

Tags: c++, overloading, mutex, operator-keyword

I want to create mutex(boost) inside the operator (=)
the code below is thread safe?

```
ub_int & operator=(const int x)
{
    mutex::scoped_lock mylock(MX_ub, defer_lock);
    mylock.lock();
        this->v=x;
    mylock.unlock();
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Defer, lock, unlock ... why?!?

Comment: I found this solution in example and it works. This is wrong ?

Comment: If you remove the defer_lock parameter you won't have to explicitly lock and unlock the mutex. The mutex will be locked as soon as you construct your scoed_lock object and will be unlocked automatically at the end of your operator= function by scoped_lock's destructor.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct, but

- as described in the comments, you should not use the defer_lock parameter
- At least in the example you probably don't need a mutex at all, as a write to an int is usually an atomic operation